# Linking between objects on different apps with Spring HATEOAS

Tags: rest, spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-hateoas, microservices

I'm investigating spring-cloud and I've set up two microservices "offers" and "customers" as eureka clients.

The customers app has:

```java
@Data
public class Customer extends ResourceSupport {
    private Long customerId;
    private String name;
}

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/customers")
@ExposesResourceFor(Customer.class)
public class CustomersController {
    ...
}
```

and the offers app has:

```java
@Data
public class Offer extends ResourceSupport {
    private final Long offerId;
    private final Long priceI;
    private final Customer customer;
}

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/offers")
@ExposesResourceFor(Offer.class)
public class OfferController {
    ...
}
```

How would I organize the code so that you can add a `Customer` link to the `Offer` instances? Autowiring an `EntityLink` would of course not work since the two controllers live in separate apps.

Would it be reasonable to create interfaces for all the controllers with the `@RequestMapping` on them and shared the inerfaces in all apps so that you could use e.g. `Link link = linkTo(methodOn(OfferController.class).getOffer(2L)).withSelfRel();`?

Comment: If the the offer service gets the customer from the customer service, then you already have the link. If not, then either the offer service is not a microservice or the two services shouldn't be separated in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how much method needs to be linked I would construct the links manually or go with sharing api-s between apps and building links from those descriptors. I wouldn't introduce a dependency for a few links.

The more interesting question is what are you planning to set as host of the link? The actual host or the eureka id of the service? I recommend setting the id of the service and then setting up a zuul instance and deal with loadbalancing and proxying in that.

P.S: When linking services i always found myself in trouble when linking them too much. Deployment speed and resiliency can greatly suffer.

Comment: The idea is to use the eureka id in the URLs like `http://OFFERS/offers/1`. Whenever possible I'd like to avoid building the links manually. What do you exactly mean with "sharing api-s between apps and building links from those descriptors"?

Comment: The same as you when you mention shared interfaces.

Comment: Sharing interfaces with `@RequestMapping` has another advantage: I just discovered that you can create `@FeignClient`s from those interfaces as well (see [here](http://projects.spring.io/spring-cloud/spring-cloud.html#spring-cloud-feign-inheritance)).

Comment: Yes, you can use `@RequestMapping` , but it behaves a little different than on a controller method. E.g: You need to specify requestmethod no matter what.