# Does Ribbon load balance spring-data-rest HAL resources links

Tags: spring-data-rest, spring-cloud, hal-json

If I have 2 instances of service A implemented using `spring-data-rest` that register themselves in `spring-cloud` `eureka` and client app B using `Ribbon` client-side load balancing would `HAL` links inside A responses be load balanced by `Ribbon` when B follows them ?

PS: I know I could build a prototype to test myself but I'm strapped for time.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, feign is only the http-client side of it, `Ribbon` does the load balancing.

Load balancing is possible if the feign clients are registered with a serviceId and not an actual host.

I am not sure what you mean by following, but if you are referencing an actual host in the links (and not serviceId-s) ribbon won't loadbalance.

I think this thread relates to your question:

[Linking between objects on different apps with Spring HATEOAS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32481469/linking-between-objects-on-different-apps-with-spring-hateoas/32482744#32482744)

Comment: My understanding is that the links inside `spring-data-rest` HAL responses (`link` or `self`) are generated by the server itself based on the incoming request. Since the requests are issued by `Ribbon` they will contain the "real" host of the server. Therefore the links will contain the particular server host. If I understand well. `Ribbon` will then not be used to load balance them. Am I wrong ?

Comment: Thanks a lot. Now maybe another question in itself. How and where (service A or service B) should I modify links to "point" to the service name instead of the "real" host ? And is that even possible ?

Comment: On the side it is produced. Something like this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22024716/spring-data-rest-base-path